# Why does Drop Index require commit?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, postgresql-9.1, ddl

In my multi-threaded program, one thread drops indexes on a table (this happens first), and other threads insert records in the same table. It so happened that when dropping index is attempted, the table gets locked and the insert transactions become *"waiting"*.

After wasting a lot of time on non-solutions to the problem, I found the real solution is to **commit** immediately after dropping the index. When **commit** is issued, the table is unlocked and the insert transactions complete successfully.

My question is, **why?** I was under the impression that Drop Index is a DDL statement and therefore does not need to be committed. Postgres seems to prove me wrong.

Comment: If you need to issue a COMMIT after dropping the index, then whatever tool you are using to connect to the db is opening a transaction. Are you using JDBC? I believe there is a toggle for autocommit mode. `DROP INDEX` needs to take out an exclusive lock long enough to execute the command, and to determine that no other transactions are using the index (otherwise you could have inconsistent or incorrect results).

Comment: You're right, it was due to opening a transaction. Had to commit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about Postgres, but DDL statements are not always auto-committed.
In Oracle for example they are, but in DB2 they are not (you can do a *create table* + *indexes* and then rollback the whole lot). I think SQL Server also needs the commit (unless auto-commit is on).

Basically (depending on the DB flavour) a DDL statement is not always auto-committed.

Comment: Commit mode is determined by the application you are connecting to the database with, and DDL is implicitly committed in most tools.
At the risk of sounding pedantic, it is "Postgres" or "PostgreSQL", not "postgress".

Comment: [Transactional DDL in PostgreSQL: A Competitive Analysis](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Transactional_DDL_in_PostgreSQL:_A_Competitive_Analysis) makes the comparison between different engines concerning transactioned DDL.

Comment: I like how in the [Wikipedia's article about DDL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language#CREATE_statements) Postgres is cited as an example.

Comment: Thank you all. That is a good link Daniel. Coming from Oracle, I (and others here) expected Postgres DDL to not require commit. Well, the more you know!

Answer (score 3):

In PostgreSQL, all DDL commands are transactional.  So if you start a transaction block, or your driver starts a transaction block for you, or your driver is not in autocommit mode, you need to commit all DDL commands, just like other SQL commands.

Other SQL databases do this differently.

(Nitpicking: Some DDL commands in PostgreSQL cannot be run in a transaction block, only in a transaction by themselves.  So you may consider those to be exceptions to the above "all DDL commands" claim.  But that's not quite the same thing as your question:  Those commands still need to be committed, they just can't be run in a transaction together with other commands.)